# Generate Dynamic term_id - returning image field - ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This works, except i want to generate the `$term_id = 22;`  Dynamically, so it's the right 'brand' per product.

```
 <?php
 $taxonomy_prefix = 'brand';
 $term_id = 22;
 $term_id_prefixed = $taxonomy_prefix .'_'. $term_id;
 $brand_logo = get_field( 'brand-logo', $term_id_prefixed );

if ( $brand_logo ) { ?>
<img src="<?php echo $brand_logo['url']; ?>" />
<?php }
?>
```

---

This code here works for Text field (brand info) - the `$term_id` is dynamic per post.. hope it clarifies my question further.

```
<?php 
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'brand' ); 
$term_id = $terms[0]->term_id;
the_field('brand info', 'term_'.$term_id); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Question not very much clear on generating term_id.

You need to decide the criterion of generating term_id. Either it should be on the basis of Post Id or some other ID.

If ypou want to assign Post Id then you can do it like

```
    global $post;

$term_id =  $post->ID;
```

However you can generate random numbers using uniqid()

Like, `$term_id = uniqid();`

OR

You can use [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) together with [pow()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) to make this happen:

```
$digits = 3;
echo rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);
```

This will output a number between 100 and 999. This because 10^2 = 100 and 10^3 = 1000 and then you need to subtract it with one to get it in the desired range.

If 005 also is a valid example you'd use the following code to pad it with leading zeros:

```
$digits = 3;
echo str_pad(rand(0, pow(10, $digits)-1), $digits, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: instead of fixed $term_id = number, i want it to be dynamic, i.e =22 when its post 22, =23 when its post 23... hope it's clear?

Comment: this code works like i want for Text field (brand info)

    <?php 
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'brand' ); 
    $term_id = $terms[0]->term_id;
    the_field('brand info', 'term_'.$term_id); 
    ?>

Comment: no it's not working same way as for text..image doesn't even render